# Removing Decimals inside a string

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to add all the values to a string builder so i can serialize it.
So, my stringbuilder looks like

```
sb = abc78.00xyz
```

Now, here i want to just remove the 0's after the decimal and want output like

```
Input       ->  Output I want
abc78.00xyz -> abc78xyz
abc78.08xyz -> abc78.08xyz
```

I tried using regex but it doesnt work
Tried :

```
sb.toString().replaceAll("\\.0*$", "")
sb.toString().replaceAll("[.0]+", "")
```

but this only works if i have numbers.

Can someone tell me how i can get the desired values ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
s = s.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\.0+(?!\\d)", "");
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KScBk1/1)

**Details**

- `(?<=\d)` - right before the current location, there must be a digit
- `\.` - a dot
- `0+` - one or more `0` digits
- `(?!\d)` - not followed with any other digit.

[Java demo](https://ideone.com/UU2yCz):

```
List<String> strs = Arrays.asList("abc78.00xyz", "abc78.08xyz");
for (String str : strs) {
    System.out.println( str.replaceAll("(?<=\\d)\\.0+(?!\\d)", "") );
}
// => abc78xyz, abc78.08xyz
```